# Creating a path in a 2D array using corners

Tags: java, algorithm, javafx

I am working on tower defense game using a 2D array to paint the map and create paths for enemies to travel on. The numbered nodes represent the path that is walkable and tells another method how to paint the map.

```
        int[][] map = new int[][]
            {
                    {0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 },
                    {0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 },
                    {0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 },
                    {0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 5 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 },
                    {0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 2 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 },
                    {0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 5 , 1 , 1 , 6 , 0 , 0 , 2 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 },
                    {0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 2 , 0 , 0 , 2 , 0 , 0 , 2 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 },
                    {0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 2 , 0 , 0 , 2 , 0 , 0 , 2 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 },
                    {0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 2 , 0 , 0 , 2 , 0 , 0 , 2 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 },
                    {1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 3 , 0 , 0 , 4 , 1 , 1 , 3 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 },
                    {0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 },
                    {0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 },
            };
```

I am now stuck trying to find a way to generate the paths. The animation part is doable for me, but I am trying to create/find an algorithm that would help in basically tracing the path and giving me the coordinates of each corner.

I have tried doing this a few ways and I started getting really messy and not functioning results.

```
for(int x = 0; x < TILE_LENGTH_X; ++x){
        for(int y = 0; y < TILE_LENGTH_Y; ++y){
            if (map[y][x] > 2 & map[y][x] <7 & y == tempCorner){
                    pathXY.add(x);
                    pathXY.add(y);
                if(correctOrder){
                    pathXY.add(tempX);
                    pathXY.add(tempY);
                    correctOrder = false;
                    tempCorner = tempY;
                }
            }
            else if(map[y][x] > 2 & map[y][x] <7 & y != tempCorner){
                if(!correctOrder){
                    pathXY.add(x);
                    pathXY.add(y);
                }
                else{
                    tempX = x;
                    tempY = y;
                    correctOrder = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the best I have come up with but fails halfway through the path. Is there some simple trick or logic I am missing here? I can think of some really messy ways to solve this but if I change the map array the results will be very unpredictable.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding is what you want.  A* is a very commonly used choice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work, but you should replace the `++x` and `++y`'s with `x++` and `y++`'s, because  the original code will ignore the entire first sub-array and the first `int` in the second array.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution that is a little cleaner than my previous attempts.

```
    public ArrayList<Coordinate> getPath(){
    ArrayList<Coordinate> pathXY = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
    boolean scanSwitch = false;
    int previousY = 0;
    int previousX = 0;

    //searches first column for first tile which is to be spawn location
    for(int y = 0; !scanSwitch; y++){
        if(map[y][0] > 0){
            pathXY.add(new Coordinate(0 , y));
            scanSwitch = true;
            previousY = y;
        }//end if - found first tile
    }//end for - found first tile

    //searches for corners by switching the search axis after each new corner is added
    findpath:
    for(int x = 0; scanSwitch; x++){
        //adds the final path coordinate before exiting loop
        if(x == TILE_LENGTH_X){
            pathXY.add(new Coordinate(x - 1 , previousY));
            break findpath;
        }//end if - no more corners
        if (map[previousY][x] > 2 & map[previousY][x] <7 & x != previousX){
            pathXY.add(new Coordinate(x , previousY));
            scanSwitch = false;
            previousX = x;
        }// end if - found corner
        for(int y = 0; !scanSwitch; y++){
            if (map[y][x] > 2 & map[y][x] <7 & y != previousY){
                pathXY.add(new Coordinate(x , y));
                scanSwitch = true;
                previousY = y;
            }// end if - found corner
        }//end for - column scan
    }//end for - row scan
    for(Coordinate num : pathXY){
        System.out.println(num);
    }
    return pathXY;
}
```